# Sounds do not play from new class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm an experienced programmer but new to iOS and Swift. I've built a tutorial Tetris game with sounds. I'm trying to refactor the code and have moved the sound routines to a designated class. The functions in the new class are being called but the sounds no longer play.

### Original code (works):

GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit
...
class GameScene: SKScene {
  ...
  runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("theme.mp3", waitForCompletion: true)))
}
```

### New code (no sound plays):

Sounds.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class Sounds: SKNode {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("NSCoder not supported") }
    override init() { super.init() }

    func playSoundtrack() {
        println( "Sounds: playSoundtrack: ")
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("theme.mp3", waitForCompletion: true)))
    }
}
```

Changed GameScene code above as follows:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
  var soundEngine: Sounds   = Sounds()
  ...
  soundEngine.playSoundtrack()
}
```

I verified the println is executed, but no sound plays. Any thoughts?

Comment: What object/node are you calling `runAction` on? Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: That was the problem, not running it on a node. No errors in console. Added the class to the scene and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's documentation

> An SKAction object is an action that is executed by a node **in the**
>   **scene**

You will need to either add `soundEngine` to the scene with

```
self.addChild(soundEngine)
soundEngine.playSoundtrack()
```

or pass the scene into the `playSoundtrack` method and run the action on the scene

```
soundEngine.playSoundtrack(self)

func playSoundtrack(SKScene *scene) {
    scene.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("theme.mp3", waitForCompletion: true)))
}
```

Of course, if you choose the latter it may be better to simply run the action from the `SKScene` subclass.

Comment: That was it -- addChild(soundEngine). Thanks so much!